# SQL grouping with partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have the following table:

```
ID  Rating  Rating_from Rating_to
1   2       2010-01-01  2011-01-01
1   2       2011-01-02  2012-02-01
1   3       2012-02-02  2013-03-01
1   2       2013-03-02  2013-04-01
1   2       2013-04-02  9999-12-31
```

It contains a rating per ID, that is checked on an ad-hoc basis. Each time the rating is checked, the last row is given a `Rating_to` date, usually the day before the new rating, and a new row is entered with a `Rating_from` date of the actual day of the rating. The `Rating_to` is set to `9999-12-31` instead of `NULL`. ‍♀️ Often, the rating remains the same. At times, the rating changes. An ID may also over time receive a rating it used to have before.

How do I get the earliest `Rating_from` date and latest `Rating_to` date, per ID, per rating, without grouping ratings that have the same rating value, but are interspersed with other ratings?

I'm trying to get the following table:

```
ID  Rating  Rating_from Rating_to
1   2       2010-01-01  2012-02-01
1   3       2012-02-02  2013-03-01
1   2       2013-03-02  NULL
```

Using the data from above, I tried grouping by `ID` and `Rating` (and setting a `MIN()` and `MAX()` on the from and to fields), but then I would only get two rows, one for rating 2 and one for rating 3, even though there were two periods of rating 2.

I asked a colleague, he suggested using `LAG()` and `LEAD()`, but I'm not sure how that will help here. The data is in SQL Server 2017, and there are around a million IDs. Any suggestions are very welcome.

I have added the below `TABLE CREATE` script with real table data, hope that helps:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
  id INT,
  rating int,
  rating_from DATE,
  rating_to DATE
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, 2, '2014-05-23', '2015-04-13'),
  (1, 2, '2015-04-14', '2015-06-02'),
  (1, 2, '2015-06-03', '2016-05-31'),
  (1, 2, '2016-06-01', '2018-03-22'),
  (2, 1, '2016-06-01', '9999-12-31'),
  (3, 3, '2016-06-01', '9999-12-31'),
  (1, 2, '2018-03-23', '2018-08-06'),
  (1, 3, '2018-08-07', '2018-08-21'),
  (1, 2, '2018-08-22', '2018-09-19'),
  (1, 2, '2018-09-20', '9999-12-31');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on [Itzik Ben-Gan's Islands approach](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/09/t-sql-queries/special-islands). It first finds rows where a change has occurred. Generates a running total of these to get a unique ID per change and then groups on the change. It's a fast and elegant approach.

```
With LagAndLead AS
(
SELECT 
ID,Rating,Rating_from,Rating_to
, CASE WHEN     LAG(Rating) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rating_from) <> Rating 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END AS IsStart
FROM tbl
),
Islands AS 
(
SELECT ID,Rating,Rating_from, rating_to
, SUM(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rating_from ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS IslandID
FROM LagAndLead
)
SELECT S.ID,MIN(S.Rating) AS Rating ,min(S.Rating_from) AS Rating_from, max(S.rating_to) AS rating_to
FROM Islands AS S
GROUP BY S.ID,S.IslandID
```

Example: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=522883a77efa18b3330704696a5f95ec)

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Thank you. It works a treat. What's important is that you don't care if the dates don't perfectly align, you're just looking for changes in the rating value. 

Comment: If it was needed it could be adapted to include gaps between the rows as well but you'd need an additional lag to get the preceding end date and bit more logic to work out the IsStart flag.

Answer (score 1):

I find that a convenient solution is similar to the `lag()` approach.  Instead of `lag()` it looks for the maximum "to date"

```
select id, rating, min(rating_from), max(rating_to)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when dateadd(day, 1, prev_rating_to) >= rating_from then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by id, rating order by rating_from) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(rating_to) over (partition by id, rating
                                        order by rating_from
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                       ) as prev_rating_to
            from tbl t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, rating, grp
order by id, rating, min(rating_from);
```

This method takes into account the `rating_to` dates as well.  So it will find gaps even when the rating does not change.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5c7bd6be315ee5ac83efec620dd03931) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

i just try one example and i wish to share with you. 
if you feel the result is OK then take that.

```
declare @temp as table 
(
    id int,
    rating int,
    rating_from date,
    rating_to date null
);

insert into @temp (id,rating,rating_from,rating_to)values
(1,2,'2010-01-01','2011-01-01'),
(1,2,'2011-01-02','2012-02-01'),
(1,3,'2012-02-02','2013-03-01'),
(1,2,'2013-03-02','2011-01-01'),
(1,2,'2013-04-02',null);

select id,rating,min(rating_from) rating_from,max(Rating_to) rating_to from @temp
group by id,rating
union 
select id,rating,max(rating_from) rating_from,max(Rating_to) rating_to from @temp
where Rating_to is null
group by id,rating
order by rating_from,rating_to


id  rating  rating_from rating_to
1   2   2010-01-01  2012-02-01
1   3   2012-02-02  2013-03-01
1   2   2013-04-02  NULL
```

I hope this will help to you...

Comment: This depends entirely on one of the periods with the same rating ending in NULL. It wouldn't work with more split periods e.g. if the rating again went back to 3 again the two separate periods with rating 2 would be merged.

Comment: No, it will not merge, because you may didn't noticed that after union i get max(rating_from) show this would work as expected.

Comment: Sadly, this won't work outside of the exact example I initially included. Have a look here at a slightly different dataset with the same logic: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2bf6f33adc17b199ea0a821a157c51f2

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query if it gives correct results and better performance:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
  ID, Rating, 
  MIN(Rating_from) AS Rating_from, 
  MAX(Rating_to) AS Rating_to
FROM (

SELECT 
  ID, Rating, Rating_from, Rating_to
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rating_from, ID) R_NUM 
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Rating, ID ORDER BY Rating_from, ID) R_NUM_Rating
FROM TEST
) AS A
WHERE A.R_NUM = A.R_NUM_Rating OR A.R_NUM_Rating = 1
GROUP BY ID, Rating

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  ID, Rating, 
  MIN(Rating_from) AS Rating_from, 
  MAX(Rating_to) AS Rating_to
FROM (

SELECT 
  ID, Rating, Rating_from, Rating_to
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rating_from, ID) R_NUM 
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Rating, ID ORDER BY Rating_from, ID) R_NUM_Rating
FROM TEST
) AS A
WHERE A.R_NUM <> A.R_NUM_Rating AND A.R_NUM_Rating <> 1
GROUP BY ID, Rating
) AS FINAL
ORDER BY 3, 1
```

Comment: In my dataset, the "end" value isn't actually NULL, it's `9999-12-31`. How will your code work with that?

Comment: I had worked on the script before the question was edited. Let me look into it...

Comment: I added a create table script with "real" data, perhaps that will help.